# How to prevent JPA query including a String constructor, throwing a NullPointerException when a null String value is only availabe

Tags: java, jpa, constructor

I have the following JPA query: select NEW java.lang.String(c.country) from Contact c group by c.country order by c.country

When one of the rows in Contact table holds null value for country field, the String constructor in the JPA query above throws a NullPointerException.

As a null value in the country field in Contact table is allowed, is there any way to prevent it via code and still use a named query?

Comment: how about using c.country != null in WHERE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
select c.country from Contact c where c.country is not null group by c.country order by c.country
```

Answer (score 1):

A group by makes no sense here, since you don't have any aggregate function in the select clause. Calling the string constructor is also useless.

Just use

```
select c.country from Contact c order by c.country
```

If the goal of the group by is to select distinct values, use `distinct`:

```
select distinct c.country from Contact c order by c.country
```